# Unable to re-install Windows 7 on a Dell Optiplex 745

Tags: windows-7, installation

During the install I receive the error code 0x80070714 with the error string *"Windows cannot install required files. Make sure all files required for installation are available, and restart the installation."*  This occurs at the end of the *Expanding Windows files...* process.

The only change from the previous re-install (the machine already had Win7), was that I had enabled bitlocker.  So after the first failed re-install attempt I disabled TPM in the BIOS (and set everything to factory defaults).  After the second failed re-install attempt I used a program called WipeDrive to nuke the HD.  But I'm still getting the install failure.

As a sanity check, I attempted to install Vista, and the install completed without a problem.

Therefore my question is, what is the 0x80070714 error code, and how can I get past it?

Comment: Are you using an original disc or a burned copy? If you're using a burned copy, try reburning the image on a new disc.

Answer (score 1):

I would check that the ISO download is valid first. You can confirm this by verifying the MD5 checksum is correct. This varies depending on your version of download, but you should be able to find it easily via Google

Something like FastSum will let you check the file : http://www.fastsum.com/press/md5-checker.php

Once you've done that, re-burn it at a slower speed and then try again.

Comment: To close the loop on this issue... I made two changes, and I'm not sure which one resolved the issue. First, I switched to a retail DVD instead of an ISO burnt onto a DVD-R. Second, I switched my partition scheme back to what it was previously. One thing I forgot to mention in the original post was that the motivation behind re-installing Windows is that I had run out of room on one of the partitions and I wanted to start over with a new layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be careful installing Windows 7 on an Optiplex GX745, i did the same with Windows 7 64 bit, and while most of the drivers were present i could not get drivers for the PCi chipset and another one, I can't remember which sorry, consequently the extra Sata ports on the Mobo wouldn't work and I lost the ability to have 2 HDD's installed as well as a DVD drive. If you do get it all working please let me know.
the other problem I ran into when installing other OS's than Vista onto the GX745 was a drive setting in the BIOS, if i remember correctly its in the Drives setting and is the SATA operation setting. Set it to legacy and see if this works. It solved my problems, so hopefully it can help yours too.